# Can't visualize image after process it with np.sqrt

Tags: python, numpy, edge-detection

I'm trying to do edge detection with the perwit kernel.

My problem is when I try to "merge" the horizontal gradient with the vertical one, because after it I get an error in the cv2.imshow() function seems like image has a distorsion.

This is my code

```
imgx = filter_image(img,kx,3)
imgy = filter_image(img,ky,3)

img_edge = np.sqrt(np.power(imgx, 2) + np.power(imgy, 2))
img_edge = (img_edge / np.max(img_edge)) * 255

print(np.shape(img_edge))
print(np.min(img_edge))
print(np.max(img_edge))

cv2.imshow('imagey',img_edge)
```

and this my output

```
(256, 256)
0.0
255.0
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-c200db56adba>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/giorg/Desktop/Elte/Image Analysis/Lab 1/filter.py', wdir='C:/Users/giorg/Desktop/Elte/Image Analysis/Lab 1')

  File "C:\Users\giorg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\giorg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/giorg/Desktop/Elte/Image Analysis/Lab 1/filter.py", line 58, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('imagey',img_edge)

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'
```

I don't know why, but I think the problem is the np.sqrt(). If i do the simply sum of imgy and imgx it works.

Comment: Looks like `np.sqrt` returns an `np.ndarray`, as it should. The error message is telling you to convert it to a cv matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing in an array of `np.float64` rather than a type openCV can understand, such as `np.unit8`. Specifically, the step after `sqrt` maps to the correct range, but does not adjust the type:

```
img_edge = (img_edge / np.max(img_edge)) * 255
```

You can tell because the min/max printouts have a decimal point in them, which normally only happens when you print floating point types.

Add one more step:

```
cv2.imshow('imagey', img_edge.astype(np.uint8))
```

Or do it separately:

```
img_edge = img_edge.astype(np.uint8)
```